# Can't set JSP value in ACE Editor (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

So I'm using this Ace Editor: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/, JSP and Java. I'm using this to send code from ace editor to Java:

```
editor.session.on('change', function(e) {
   document.myform3.userCode.value = editor.getSession().getValue();
});

<form action="/myPage" method="post" name="myform3">
   <input type="hidden" name="userCode" value="">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And I'm returing it in Java:

```
public ModelAndView checkUserCode(String userCode) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("kurs");
    model.addObject("testunio", userCode);
    return model;
}
```

And I'm setting it with this code:

```
editor.getSession().setValue("${testunio}");
```

And it doesn't work. I don't see anything, even my editor disapear. I see just "Submit" button and nothing more. But when I display it normally in html:

```
<html><body>
${testunio}
</body></html>
```

It works. And also when I do for example in Java:

```
public ModelAndView checkUserCode(String userCode) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("kurs");
    userCode = "test test test test test";
    model.addObject("testunio", userCode);
    return model;
}
```

`editor.getSession().setValue("${testunio}");` works ok. Somebody have maybe any idea what I'm doing wrong?

@edit

Maybe it will be better if I will give more my code:

```
<div id="editor"></div>

<form action="/myPage" method="post" name="myform3">
   <input type="hidden" name="userCode" value="">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sh");
    editor.getSession().setValue("${testunio}");

    editor.session.on('change', function(e) {
        document.myform3.userCode.value = editor.getSession().getValue();
    });
</script>
```